# Asp.net Dynamic Data - Field not rendered on List page

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, scaffolding

I have created a Dynamic Data site against an Entity Framework Model

I have 2 fields which are nvarchar(max) in the DB and they do not get rendered on the list view

This is probably a sensible default

But how do I override this?

Have tried adding various attributes to my MetaData class e.g

```
[ScaffoldColumn(true)]
[UIHint("RuleData")]
```

But no joy with that

Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to get nvarchar(max) to show up in the other views? like details or edit? I cannot see  nvarchar(max) field in any view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this can't be overidden in the version of DD I am using
Had to change the data type from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(4000), which will probably be sufficient